# Backslash import files laravel not working

Tags: laravel, backslash

Error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Log' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectfolder\app\Logger.php:16

Code its using :

```
     \log::bug()
```

Not imported, I am using Backslash to import files but not working

Same code work on some other system, but problem in my system only

Comment: Backslash does not import files. It references the global namespace. Also class names are case sensitive so a class named `Log` will need to be referenced as `Log`.

Comment: Same code work on some other system, but problem in my system only

Comment: Check your `app.php` it should have an `aliases` section which might include log somewhere. By default it should be `'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,` which means you need to reference it as `\Log` but in the other system it might have been changed to `log`. In general I would recommend "importing" and using Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class directly as aliases overcrowd the global namespace and can easily conflict